# Source data remains same after call of MoveMemory()?

Tags: windows, mfc

MoveMemory function on Windows Says "Moves a block of memory from one location to another." ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/aa366788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

well, what about source ater calling MoveMemory?
I wonder if source data remains same even after call of MoveMemory.

Can I access to source after call of movememory, or I have to access to Destination?

Comment: Due to overlap, it is possible that the contents of the source are changed by the operation.

Comment: @RaymondChen If so, In case of overlap: source changes / else source does not changes?